# Opacity of "previous paragraphs" in macOS Keynote's "Highlighted paragraph" animation

Tags: macos, keynote

In the latest version of Keynote on macOS, you can animate text by "Highlighted paragraph" which de-emphasized previous paragraphs. My presentation has the "Modern Type" theme, so the animation turns lighter gray to darker gray. I like this and want to recreate the same "darkening effect" in diagrams, for instance, by adding "Opacity" actions there to elements manually. Two questions:

- I gave a presentation, and the "darkened" paragraphs were hard to read. Where can I change the opacity of a "darkened previous paragraphs" in the "Highlighted paragraph" animation?
- If I can't change the opacity in the "Highlighted paragraph" animation: What's the value of the opacity? Seems around 35% to me.